# Responsive flow dilemma with horizontal items

Tags: css, media-queries

For my site I have used one css class multiple times already and it has always fine until now.

This is a skinned down version of it:

```
.list {
    font-size: 0;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
}

.list__item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .list__item {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This is of course working perfectly if you never want the left item to be under the right item. Now this is what I've encountered now and I'm looking for a non-dirty or too much code approach of doing this.

I've also created a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/sjbe00nk/1/.

So the wanted behavior is that I want the left block to be under the right block.

Comment: Please state the expected and actual encountered css behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floats to change the layout when responsive screens, but this is primarily done by changing the order of the items, then adjusting the horizontal positioning with CSS.

#### Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sjbe00nk/2/

First change the order of the items:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item right">
        right
    </div>
    <div class="list__item left">
        left
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can adjust their floats, and clear the floats when responsive.

```
.list__item {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
```

A **much** better way of doing all of this though is by using flexbox, though support for it is not 100% yet – see this article on how that would work: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ – flexbox would be a better way of doing this if you are developing an internal system for example, where you can guarantee what browser people will be viewing on.

Comment: I know about Flexbox, but this site has to be compatible with IE8. So too bad!